# Express.js, Mongoose: Populate returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm learning **express.js** and **mongoDB** and want to create a functionality, where **user** should be able add products.
My code contains 2 models, **User** and **Product**. User has a reference to **Product**. In **User** query when i try to populate **Product**', **null** is returned.
I'm testing it with **postman**, and the result is **null** in **cart**. 
I am a beginner and don't understand how to solve the issue.

user schema

```
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose'
import { ProductDocument } from './Products'

export type UserDocument = Document & {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  password: string;
  email: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  cart: ProductDocument[];
  resetLink: string;
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 64,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 64,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  cart: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Products',
    },
  ],
  resetLink: {
    data: String,
    default: '',
  },
})

export default mongoose.model<UserDocument>('Users', userSchema)
```

product schema

```
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose'

export type ProductDocument = Document & {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  categories: string[];
  variants: string[];
  sizes: number[];
}

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  categories: [String],
  variants: [String],
  sizes: [Number],
})

export default mongoose.model<ProductDocument>('Products', productSchema)
```

and the controller for responsible for populating

```
export const getProduct = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const { productId } = await req.body
        const productBought = await Products.findOne({ _id: productId }).then(
            (product) => {
                return product
            }
        )
        console.log(productBought)

        const updated = await Users.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.userId },
            { $push: { cart: productBought } },
            { new: true }
        )
            .populate('cart')
            .exec()
        return res.json(updated)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'does not work' })
    }
}
```

output from **postman**

```
{
    "isAdmin": false,
    "cart": [
        null,
        null
    ],
    "_id": "5f894b3c06b4a108f8d9a7ab",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "password": "$2b$08$rA0/r8iVBWeSyyerPDpPWO.ztgouQoseX0QFBZ.mlPgb6tELlrhpy",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your "cart" like[ObjectId,ObjectId], but your "productBought" like[{},{}].

try `let cart = [];productBought.forEach((v,k) => {cart[k] = v._id});`

and use `{ $push: { cart: { $each: cart } },`